# Heatmap of PWM with image() function

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to use the `image()` function, to plot a heatmap with two colours, black and white, but I don't know how.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

We can use *fields* package to plot image, see example.

First, let's get example PWM data from *seqLogo* package, and convert it to matrix object:

```
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("seqLogo")
library(seqLogo) # bioconductor

# get example matrix
mFile <- system.file("Exfiles/pwm1", package="seqLogo")
m <- read.table(mFile)

plotDat <- as.matrix(m)
plotDat
#       V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
# [1,] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.3 0.2 0.0 0.0 0.0
# [2,] 0.8 0.2 0.8 0.3 0.4 0.2 0.8 0.2
# [3,] 0.2 0.8 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.8 0.2 0.8
# [4,] 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Now we can use fields image function to plot, we need to specify the colours, note we could use `graphics::image(plotDat)` but `fields::image.plot` has more plot customisation options:

```
library(fields)

image.plot(plotDat, col = c("black", "white"))
```

[image]